# Customize the tooltip of Struts2 jquery grid column

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip, struts2-jquery-grid

I am usimg struts 2 jquery grid. On mouse over it shows a tooltip of the data in that particular column. But instead of that I want the entire row to display the same tooltip of the basic details ie. The details of all the columns of that particular row. Can anyone help mi how to go about it??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered the usability? Hovering a column and seeing 10 tooltips all around coming out is a bit aggressive :|

Comment: @A Only one single tooltip will be seen showing the details of the complete row. Is that possible??

Comment: Ah ok. [Take a look at this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/tooltip-on-row-hover-with-ajax-content-solution)